# MySQL column name standards / conventions

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions

I'm looking for document (suggestions) with column name standards or conventions for MySQL. Can anybody suggest any?

Answer (score 12):

There's nothing "standard" in this space I'm aware of, unlike say Sun's old Java conventions. Anything you adopt will be personal/company preference.

That said, I do like prefix conventions:

- t_ for table
- v_ for view
- idx_ for index
- tx_ for text field
- dt_ for date field
- n_ for numeric field
- id_ for identify field
- nm_ for something that's specifically a *name*
- is_ for booleans, whether 0/1, yes/no or otherwise
- fk_ as an optional foreign key identifer; you may prefer to stick with id_ though, to keep the field the same as its primary key counterpart, e.g. id_customer -> id_customer, rather than an fk_customer

Answer (score 5):

Naming conventions comes into play when using frameworks like Ruby on Rails or Zend that subscribe to *[convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)*. Anything that will scaffold forms for you or "auto discover" your database. Looking at these conventions could also help you decide on a naming strategy even if you are not using a framework.