# Mysql Exclude and Include based on countries

Tags: mysql, include, subquery, exists

I have a logical problem that I need to solve.
We have the following tables:

1. `200` - Article table(all the articles)
2. `202` - Country restrictions table(all the restrictions based on countries and articles)

If an article has no result in the country restrictions table, then the article is okay to be displayed.

If an article has results in the country restrictions table but the country that we are interested in is not present, then the article is okay be to displayed.

If the article has results in the country restriction table and the country that we are interested in it is present and the exclusive value is 0, then the article is okay to be displayed.

IF the article has results in the country restriction table and other countries have exclusive 1, than the product is okay to be displayed.

This is my approach but not a good one...

```
SELECT `203`.ArtNr, 
    IF(
        EXISTS((SELECT * FROM `202` WHERE `202`.ArtNr = `203`.ArtNr)),
            '',
            'yes'
    ) as 'Display' FROM `203`
WHERE `203`.RefNr_Search = 'GDB400'
AND `203`.ArtNr IN ('0 986 467 720','0 986 494 522','0 986 TB2 005','F 03A 150 016')
```

**The LKZ values can be these: 'RO','EU','OE'**

This is the selection for these 4 articles. The above query should return only two results(ArtNr=0 986 494 522, ArtNr=0 986 467 720). I cannot make this query ... help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `203` (
    `ArtNr` VARCHAR(22) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ArtNr_Search` VARCHAR(22) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `DLNr` INT(4) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SA` SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `KHerNr` INT(6) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LKZ` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `RefNr` VARCHAR(22) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `RefNr_Search` VARCHAR(22) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Exclude` INT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Sort` INT(5) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `ArtNr` (`ArtNr`),
    INDEX `ArtNr_Search` (`ArtNr_Search`),
    INDEX `RefNr` (`RefNr`),
    INDEX `RefNr_Search` (`RefNr_Search`),
    INDEX `KHerNr` (`KHerNr`),
    INDEX `DLNr` (`DLNr`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=FIXED
;

INSERT INTO `203` (`ArtNr`, `ArtNr_Search`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `KHerNr`, `LKZ`, `RefNr`, `RefNr_Search`, `Exclude`, `Sort`) VALUES ('0 986 467 720         ', '0986467720', 30, 203, 520, '   ', 'GDB400                ', 'GDB400', 0, 5);
INSERT INTO `203` (`ArtNr`, `ArtNr_Search`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `KHerNr`, `LKZ`, `RefNr`, `RefNr_Search`, `Exclude`, `Sort`) VALUES ('0 986 494 522         ', '0986494522', 30, 203, 520, '   ', 'GDB400                ', 'GDB400', 0, 5);
INSERT INTO `203` (`ArtNr`, `ArtNr_Search`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `KHerNr`, `LKZ`, `RefNr`, `RefNr_Search`, `Exclude`, `Sort`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005         ', '0986TB2005', 30, 203, 798, '   ', 'GDB400                ', 'GDB400', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO `203` (`ArtNr`, `ArtNr_Search`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `KHerNr`, `LKZ`, `RefNr`, `RefNr_Search`, `Exclude`, `Sort`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016         ', 'F03A150016', 30, 203, 520, '   ', 'GDB400                ', 'GDB400', 0, 5);

CREATE TABLE `202` (
`ArtNr` VARCHAR(22) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`DLNr` INT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SA` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`LKZ` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Exclude` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
INDEX `ArtNr_LKZ` (`ArtNr`, `LKZ`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=FIXED
;


INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 467 720', 30, 202, 'BR', 1);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 467 720', 30, 202, 'CDN', 1);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 467 720', 30, 202, 'USA', 1);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'ADN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'AN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'ANG', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'BF', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'BRN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'CD', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'CI', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'CM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'DJ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'DY', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'DZ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'EAK', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'EAT', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'EAU', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'ER', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'ET', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'ETH', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'GA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'GH', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'GN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'GQ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'GW', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'IL', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'IR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'IRQ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'JOR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'KM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'KWT', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'LAR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'LB', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'LS', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'MA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'MEA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'MS', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'MW', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'MZ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'OM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'Q', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RB', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RCA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RCB', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RE', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RIM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RL', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RMM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RU', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'RWA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'SA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'SN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'SP', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'ST', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'SY', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'SYR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'SZ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'TD', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'TG', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'TN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'TR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'UAE', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'WAG', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'WAL', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'WAN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'Z', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('0 986 TB2 005', 30, 202, 'ZW', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ADN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'AN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ANG', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'AS', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'BF', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'BRN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'C', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'CD', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'CI', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'CM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'CR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'DJ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'DOM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'DY', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'EAK', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'EAT', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'EAU', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ER', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ES', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ET', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ETH', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'GA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'GCA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'GH', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'GN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'GQ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'GW', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'HN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'IR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'IRQ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'JOR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'KM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'KWT', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'LAR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'LB', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'LS', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'MEX', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'MW', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'MZ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'NIC', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'OM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'PA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'Q', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RB', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RCA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RCB', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RIM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RL', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RMM', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RU', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'RWA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'SA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'SN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'SP', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ST', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'SY', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'SYR', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'SZ', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'TD', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'TG', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'UAE', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'WAG', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'WAL', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'WAN', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'Z', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ZA', 0);
INSERT INTO `202` (`ArtNr`, `DLNr`, `SA`, `LKZ`, `Exclude`) VALUES ('F 03A 150 016', 30, 202, 'ZW', 0);
```

Comment: Its very difficult to work with this kind of naming standards. Please refer the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325520/mysql-column-name-standards-conventions.  Also the data inside tables are annoying.

Comment: @AdarshGangadharan This is a article lookup table, I just want to display two lines from it based on countries(LKZ) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help from a friend of mine, thank you.

```
SELECT distinct (`203`.ArtNr) FROM `203` 
    LEFT JOIN `202` ON `202`.ArtNr = `203`.ArtNr
    WHERE `203`.RefNr_Search = 'gdb400'
        AND `203`.ArtNr IN ('0 986 467 720','0 986 494 522','0 986 TB2 005','F 03A 150 016')
            AND (`202`.ArtNr IS NULL OR (`202`.Exclude = 0 AND `202`.LKZ IN('RO','EU','OE')) OR (`202`.Exclude = 1 AND `202`.LKZ NOT IN('RO','EU','OE')))
```